# Simple yet important 4 questions about Visual Basic Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, passwords, range, radio-group

Guys I'm a student who knows simple stuff about Visual Basic Studio 2012 and who's working on creating an application for a course project. :)

I'm using ASP.Net Empty Website under Visual C# 
If that makes sense. xD

Anyways, I have 4 important yet simple questions:

Q1: how do I apply Password Custom Vlaidation? For example 8 characters min in both the password and the password confirm text feild?

Q2: How do I apply "required" validation to a group of radio buttons, check boxes and a drop down list?

Q3: In a form, how do I get a list of radio buttons appear as options for once a customer picks a hair style category, however if she picks a make up categorty from the same drop down list, a whole different options appear? I hope it's clear lol

Q4: Is there a "range" tool in Visual Basic 2012 and how do I use it?

I appreciate every answer and so much thanks in advance. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ASP.NET

**Ans1:**

Use RegularExpressionValidator instead of CustomValidator

**Ans2:**

Use RequiredFieldValidator with all the controls. And in the last use single ValidationSummary Control to display message. Here is link for you [Understanding ASP.NET Validation Techniques](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/334310/Understanding-ASP-NET-Validation-Techniques)

**Ans3:**

Use RadioButtonList control for options.
On SelectedIndexChange event of DropdownList control populate the RadioButtonList with relevant options.

**Ans4:**

Link in Ans2 will give you the RangeValidator control example.

Comment: If my answer helped you then please vote is up. And accept my answer .

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working in Winform.

And Since I am a C# developer I am posting my code in C#. you can use [Telerik Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/) to convert it to VB.NET

**Ans1:**

```
char[] charArray = s.ToCharArray();

int passwordCharacters = charArray.Length;
if (passwordCharacters < 8)
{
    //Your code
}
```

**Ans2:**

Use ErrorProvider Control

**Ans3:**

There is no data bound RadioButtonList control in Winform. You will have to do it manually.

**Ans4:**

I don't think so there is any ASP.NET like Range Validator Control in VB.NET

Comment: Thanks! I'm sorry, could you please calrify your answers a bit more? I'm using ASP.Net Empty website under C# if that makes sense. :D

Comment: Check my second answer.